# Return multiple row numbers for a particular value in one column in Excel

Tags: excel

I have ColumnA with dates (stating month, day, year) in ascending order. I want to identify the row numbers in ColumnA with the year 1980, row numbers with 1981, etc.

I thought it would be easier if I first create another column that only contains the year (since I don't need the the month and day), and then use a formula that will call the row number of the cells containing that specific year.

With the Match formula, it only returns 1 row number. I want to call all row numbers that contain the specific year.

Comment: So what do you want the output to look like? Do you want a cell that has an array of row numbers?

Comment: I want to be able to summarize in adjacent rows something like this: 1980 1-5, where 1 and 5 refer to the first and last row where 1980 is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this. Assuming you have your years in column A from row 1 to 10, put this in cell B1:

```
=MATCH(1980, A1:A9,0 )
```

and this in cell B2:B10:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1980, INDIRECT("A" & TEXT(B1+1, "0") & ":A10" ), 0)+B1), MATCH(1980, INDIRECT("A" & TEXT(B1+1, "0") & ":A10" ), 0)+B1, "")
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This takes me one step closer to what I want to achieve. But my Column A has 365 entries which still requires me to scroll down to know at which row a year ends. For example, I want to know the start row and end row that contains 1995. And the first record of 1995 is at row 255 and it goes all the way to 276. Is there a formula to know just the starting row and end row?

Comment: Np, glad I could help. Well the first row will always be displayed in cell B1. To get the last row you could use another match function in cell C1 to find the first empty cell in column B and return the value of the cell before it using another indirect function.

Comment: Mmm...I think I may have been unclear. This is how my data looks like right now: http://i.cubeupload.com/JSvMFS.png. Can I summarize, for example, that 1981 can be found in rows 10-16? Or 1984 are in rows 17-30?

Comment: Yes, as I've mentioned using another match and indirect function in cell C1 will get you the range.